# Best way to monitor bandwidth

Tags: c#, networking, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Which is the best way to measure the download speed in real time (or as close as possible) in a windows store application. I have been searching for a solution and have yet to come across one or something similar.

Is there a windows store class that will be able to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, if you are downloading manually, you can calculate the [download speed manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507870/calculating-current-not-average-download-speed).

The [Performance Counters](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Network-Bandwidth-8d7e8f0a) are not supported since it requires registry access to work, not permitted in a Windows Store app.

Comment: Thanks alot. I will try this now and see how i get on. Thanks so much. :D

Comment: Unfortunately, the performance counters are not supported on the windows store apps for security.

Comment: I have found this class which im going to play around with and see if i can get it working.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketinformation.bandwidthstatistics.aspx